# C pointer dynamic allocation

Tags: arrays, pointers, dynamic, struct

How to allocate memory dynamically for struct array pointer. 
Ex: I have a struct array pointer which is of size 1024 but if i need to increase the size how to do it?
I need the arr size to be defined dynamically. For the initialization, I kept the size to 1024.
I need to increase the space later when it is more than allocated , how to increase it ??

Comment: Can you post structure declaration / definition ?

Answer (score 1):

[`realloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/realloc.html). Something like

```
struct foo *ptr;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * 1024);

// later
struct foo *tmp = realloc(ptr, sizeof(*ptr) * 2048);
if (tmp) {
    ptr = tmp;
} else {
    // something nasty happened
    free(ptr);
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: like I have something like struct abc{};  abc *arr[1024]; now I need to change arr[1024] to 2048

Comment: You can't do that. One similar thing you can do is variable-length arrays, but it's still not identical.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic memory allocation, using `array implemented using linked lists` will help. 
You can use `malloc()` function to allocate memory to an existing structure node.

If you want the array in a structure object to increase its memory, then you can use linked list instead of array inside structure.